# Lightbox opens below the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, lightbox, lightbox2

I'm trying to use lightbox2 (http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) on my wordpress theme because all plugins I tried don't work. The links on my testbloge (http://test.raoulwittenberns.com/blog/) are opening the lightbox but it's opening below the page content and causes the user to scroll down.

Anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it? I'm not using any other plugins and I've tried excluding all other scripts to no succes.

Thanks a bunch!

Raoul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link to the lightbox.css is incorrect --> ellaelisabethlightbox.css.

I imagine it is -->ellaelisabeth/lightbox.css ?

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" src="http://test.raoulwittenberns.com/wp-content/themes/ellaelisabethlightbox.css" media="all" />
```

Should be :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="http://test.raoulwittenberns.com/wp-content/themes/ellaelisabeth/lightbox.css" media="all" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply.
Unfortunately adding a / did not help. The lightbox is still opening beneath the content.

I've only checked this on my cellphone.

Thanks, 
Raoul

Comment: Try loading your lightbox.css before lightbox.js